# Crontab not executing script that change background

Tags: linux, debian, cron

I have this script to change the background and screensaver from my gnome desktop. Works fine when executing manually, but when I put it in cron it doesn't execute it. The file is executable.

I added the cron job with *crontab -e*.

This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# change_background - Change desktop background and lockscreen background randomly

# Export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS environment variable
euid=$(id --real --user)
pid=$(pgrep --euid $euid gnome-session)
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$pid/environ|cut -d= -f2-)

# Wallpapers directory
dir="/home/myuser/Pictures/Wallpapers"

# Wallpaper and screensaver files
background=$(ls $dir/* | shuf -n1)
screensaver=$(ls $dir/* | shuf -n1)

# Set the wallpaper and screensaver
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file://$background
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver picture-uri file://$screensaver
```

My script is in my bin directory */home/myuser/bin* which is added to the PATH variable.

*crontab -l* output:

```
# ┌───────────── minute (0 - 59) 
# │ ┌───────────── hour (0 - 23) 
# │ │ ┌───────────── day of month (1 - 31) 
# │ │ │ ┌───────────── month (1 - 12) 
# │ │ │ │ ┌───────────── day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday to Saturday; 
# │ │ │ │ │ 7 is also Sunday on some systems) 
# │ │ │ │ │ 
# │ │ │ │ │ 
# * * * * * command
#
# --- Change background every minute --- #
#
* * * * * change_background 
#
# --- ------------------------------ --- #
```

My question is: why cron is not executing my script? what I'm doing wrong?.

Comment: Note that if you added `/home/myuser/bin` to `PATH` in `myuser`'s `.bashrc` file (or `.bash_profile` or similar), then this may not be parsed.  Instead, modify `PATH` in the crontab.  Do you get any errors from the cron daemon emailed to you? (these ought to have been sent to the `myuser` account).

Comment: Where do you modify `PATH`? What errors do you get?

Comment: @Kusalananda thank you. I checked the email file which is located in */var/spool/mail/myuser* and the output says that it doesn't found the command, as you said the problem was in the PATH variable. So with *crontab -e* I added the correct PATH and also set the SHELL variable to */bin/bash* and now cron execute the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue [seems to have been](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/498906/crontab-not-executing-script-that-change-background#comment918560_498906) that the environment in the crontab was not set up with a correct `PATH`, so the script was never found.  The user's shell initialisation files are not run by cron, so setting the `PATH` or other variables therein is useless for a cron job.

This can be solved in a number of ways.

One is to simply set `PATH` (and any other variables that needs specific values) in the crontab (this would also change the value of these variables for the script and *all other jobs* in the crontab):

```
PATH=/home/myuser/bin:$PATH
```

Another is to execute the script with an absolute path:

```
* * * * * /home/myuser/bin/change_background
```

This may be preferable if other jobs are executed that need an individually modified `PATH` variable for specific things that the scripts themselves are using (the scripts themselves would then set `PATH` early on, or be started with e.g. `env PATH=... /some/path/program`).

Comment: Yes that was the problem, thank you!. I'll better go with the absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
   * * * * * env DISPLAY=:0 /path/to/bash/script.sh
```